# Difference between simple Github-Pages Themes and creating a site with Jekyll using a Gemfile

Tags: github, jekyll, github-pages, jekyll-theme

Github documents two different ways of configuring and theming Jekyll-based Pages sites.

1. [Creating sites with Jekyll, using a custom Gemfile](https://docs.github.com/en/pages/setting-up-a-github-pages-site-with-jekyll/creating-a-github-pages-site-with-jekyll)
2. [Adding themes to Pages sites, without adding a Gemfile to the repo](https://docs.github.com/en/pages/setting-up-a-github-pages-site-with-jekyll/adding-a-theme-to-your-github-pages-site-using-jekyll)

What is the difference between the two approaches? Specifically

- Are both functionally equivalent, or is the second approach more restrictive in terms of theming? If so, what are the restrictions?
- Is the second approach still generating a Gemfile in the background? If so, is there a way to access it or know what it specifies?
- Relatedly, can one imitate the second approach using the first approach by specifying a certain Gemfile?
- Does one need to use the first approach in order to preview pages locally? Or could one deploy using the second approach, and then just add a Gemfile locally for the preview?
- More generally, what are the pros & cons of using the two different approaches?